# uploading files in android using emulator and localsystem

Tags: android

hi friends iam trying to upload a file from the android device to the server.i tried it with emulator and localhost  but it does not working.
i am using wamp server in local system . my android code for upload file is given below. i need  uploading file from emulator to localsystem

upload.java

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;
DataInputStream inStream = null;
String existingFileName =FileName.getText().toString();
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
//String responseFromServer = "";
String urlString="http://localhost/uploads/upload.php";

try
{

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
 URL url = new URL(urlString);

 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

 conn.setDoInput(true);

 conn.setDoOutput(true);

 conn.setUseCaches(false);

 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
 dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 while (bytesRead > 0)
 {
  dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 }

 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

 Log.e("Debug","File is written");
 fileInputStream.close();
 dos.flush();
 dos.close();
 Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "Files have been uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (MalformedURLException ex)
{
     Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
     Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
}

try {
      inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
      String str;

      while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
      {
           Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
      }
      inStream.close();

}
catch (IOException ioex)
{
     Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
}
```

here is my php code

upload.php

```
<?php

 $target_path = "uploads/";

 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
 } 

 else{
      echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
   }
   ?>
```

i have a folder named uploads in the www directory of wamp folder.and i need to store the uploaded file in this folder.

but when i run the android program it shows error message as

```
"java.net.Connect Exception: localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused"
```

can anybody give me a solution for this and let me know my coding are enough to achieve my target.  thanks in advance

Comment: Is the file upload going to be a part of your application, or are you just trying to exchange files between the emulator / local PC for testing purposes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user664525 
From the `"java.net.Connect Exception: localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused"` it seems that Android is trying to refer to its own localhost not your server's address.

You need to provide the IP address of your server's machine(in your case your own system's say 192.168.40.24) not the **localhost** in your code.

Comment: do i have to mention any port number in which the wampserver is running with the ip address,if so how can i do it

Comment: @user664525 **ServerIP:PortNo.** say 192.168.40.24:443

Comment: i think you not get my problem ,my system is stand alone not connected with any network.in which i am running both emulator and local php server .now how can i specify this local server address in my android page

Comment: @user664525 You Simply need to find your system's IP address by using `ifconfig`(in linux) or `ipconfig`(in windows) & use that IP address in place of `localhost`

Comment: I just removed signature links from a bunch of your recent posts, so I wanted to point out the those are prohibited on Stack Overflow.  From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures),  "Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page."  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In emulator, the SDCard is not having the read/write/execute permission and unfortunately there is no way to set these permissions for the emulator's SDCard. To test your code, I recommend to put your file in `asset` of your application and use `AssetManager` to get reference of that file and upload it.

By this way you can atleast test the upload algo and I am sure if that works, It will also work on actual device.

Comment: but the error i got is "java.net.Connect Exception: localhost/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused"   how can i solve it

Comment: use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

Change The Following Line Of Code:

```
String urlString="http://localhost/uploads/upload.php";
```

to

```
String urlString="http://10.0.2.2:portno/uploads/upload.php";
```

Explanation:

Note here the IP Address 10.0.2.2 refers to the Localmachine's IP Address.
Whereas localhost refer's to the emulator's IP itself.
Also the "portno" Will Usually Be The Post No On Which Your Server Services Are Running Usually 80(By Default)..

HOPE This Helps..!! ;)