# Issue in uploading image to a local host in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application, in which I have to upload image to a local host, I have created a database, also put the php file,,,,,

I did r&d.and tried the way in this url
[uploading files in android using emulator and localsystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375227/uploading-files-in-android-using-emulator-and-localsystem)

But did not get success..... My localhost url is http://localhost/connect1.php

Can anyone guide me how to upload image to a local host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `http://localhost` is only valid on your computer.  For Android to find the server, it will need a real url.

For development, if you don't have an official URL yet, you can put your phone on your local wireless network and use the IP address of your local webserver.  To get the ip address run `ipconfig` (windows) or `ifconfig` (linux).  So your url will be something like `http://10.23.234.12/connect1.php`

Comment: ,,,i have placed my php file in wamp docs,,and my phpfile is http://pastebin.com/rY81mCsz.....,,,,can u just guide how to upload image to local host....Regards